# Kubernetes test environment

Tags: kubernetes, virtualhost

I have a hosted VPS and I would like to use this machine as a single node Kubernetes test environment. Is it possible to create a single-node Kubernetes cluster on the VPS, deploy pods to it using, for example, GitLab and test the application from outside the machine? I would like to locally develop, push to git and then deploy on this testing/staging environment.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the part of whole question:

> I have a hosted VPS and I would like to use this machine as a single node kubernetes test environment.

A good starting point could be to cite the parts of my own answer from [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1046581/is-it-possible-to-install-kubernetes-manually-in-my-existing-gcp-vm-instance/1047006#1047006):

> There are a lot of options to choose from. Each solution will have it's advantages and disadvantages. It will also depend on the operating system your VM is deployed with.
>
> **Some** of the options are the following:
>
> - [MicroK8S](https://microk8s.io/) - as pointed by user @Sekru
> - [Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/)
> - [Kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/)
> - [Kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/)
> - [Kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray)
> - [Kelsey Hightower: Kubernetes the hard way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way)
>
> Each of the solutions linked above have a link to it's respective homepage. You can find there installation steps/tips. Each solution is different and I encourage you to check if selected option suits your needs.

You'll need to review the networking part of each of above solutions as some of them will have easier/more difficult process to expose your workload outside of the environment (make it accessible from the Internet).

It all boils down to what are your requirements/expectations and what are the requirements for each of the solutions.

---

#### MicroK8S setup:

I do agree with an answer provided by community member @Sekru but I also think it could be beneficiary to add an example for such setup. Assuming that you have a `microk8s` compatible OS:

- `sudo snap install microk8s --classic`
- `sudo microk8s enable ingress`
- `sudo microk8s kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx`
- `sudo microk8s kubectl expose deployment nginx --port=80 --type=NodePort`
- `sudo microk8s kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml` where `ingress.yaml` is a file with following content:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: public # <-- IMPORTANT
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx
            port:
              number: 80
```

After above steps you should be able to contact your `Deployment` from the place outside of your host by:

- `curl http://IP-ADDRESS`

> Side notes!
>
> - A setup like that will allow expose your workload on a `NodePort` (allocated port on each node from `30000` to `32767`).
> - From the security perspective I would consider using your `VPS` provider firewalls to limit the traffic coming to your instance to allow only subnets that you are connecting from.

---

From the perspective of Gitlab integration with Kubernetes, I'd reckon you could find useful information by following it's page:

- *[About.gitlab.com](https://about.gitlab.com/)*

Additional resources about Kubernetes:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Home](https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/)*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use microk8s. For access from outside, use ingress addon

Comment: Hi @Sekru thank you! At the moment I have minikube running on the vps with the provided ingress running. However, the ingress is exposing the minikube cluster only to the machine hosting it. I know I can use ngrok to port forward the ingress ip and port to a port of the vps. But is there another way of doing this? thank you

Comment: Microk8s not use virtual machine so you can access ingress from outside of cluster